# How can i output my program results to a file

Tags: nsfilehandle

This is the code I wrote. I am trying to output the results to a file. I used the `open()` but it does not work. Can someone please tell me what to do?

AP. result is the file in which I would like to copy the result to. However it does not copy. The results are still showing in the screen.

```
open (Host, >, AP.results) or die;
     
        for my $key (@keyA){
            printf "%-5i %-6.2f %-12s\n", $hash{$key}, 100*($hash{$key}/$logcount), $key;
        }
        print "----\n$logcount entries displayed\n\n";
    
    }
    
    
    
    my $resCount =0;
    my $logcount = 0 ; 
    my $bs = 0;
    for my $i (@ARGV){
    open IN, $i;
        my $regex= '(.*?)\s-.*?-\s\[(.*?):(.*?)\s-.*?\]\s"(.*?)\s(.*?)\s(.*?)\s(.*?)\s(.*?)\s"(.*?)"\s"(.*)';
        while (my $data = <IN>){
            if ($data =~ $regex){
                $logcount++;
                my $paddr = $1;
            
                my $pdate = $2;
                my $pstatus = $7;
                my $pURL = $5;
                my $pTime = $3;
                $bs +=$8;
                my $pUserAgent = $10; 
                if ($9 eq '-'){
                    $referer{'NO REFERER'}++;
                    $rdomain{'NO REFERER'}++;
                }else{
                    $referer{$9}++;
                    if($9 =~ '.*\/\/(?:www\.){0,1}([^\/\s]*)'){
                        $rdomain{$1}++;
                    }
                }
                my $domain = $paddr;
    
                $ip{$paddr}++;
                $date{$pdate}++;    
                $status{$pstatus}++;        
                $URL{$pURL}++;
                $userAgent{$pUserAgent}++;  
                if ( $pTime =~ '(\d+):.*' ){
                    $hour{$1}++;
                }   
                if ($pURL =~ '.*(\.[^\/\s]*).*'){
                    $resource{$1}++;
                    $resCount++;
                }
                if ($pUserAgent =~'.*Microsoft.*'){
                    $OS{Windows}++;
                }elsif($pUserAgent =~'.*Mac OS X.*'){
                    $OS{Macintosh}++;
                }elsif($pUserAgent =~'.*Linux.*'){
                    $OS{Linux}++;
                }else{
                    $OS{Other}++;
                }
    
                if ($pUserAgent =~'.*Mozilla.*'){
                    $aFamily{Firefox}++;
                }elsif ($pUserAgent =~'.*Chrome.*'){
                    $aFamily{Chrome}++;
                }elsif ($pUserAgent =~'.*(Internet Explorer|MSIE).*'){
                    $aFamily{'Internet Explorer'}++;
                }elsif ($pUserAgent =~'.*Opera.*'){
                    $aFamily{Opera}++;
                }elsif ($pUserAgent =~'.*Safari.*'){
                    $aFamily{Safari}++;
                }else{
                    $aFamily{Unknown}++;
                }
                
                #print "$pURL\n";
    
            }
        }
        close IN;   
    }   
    my @fdate = sort(keys %date);
    my @fip = sort(keys %ip);
    my @fhour = sort(keys %hour);
    my @fstatus = sort(keys %status);
    my @fURL = sort(keys %URL);
    my @fResource = sort(keys %resource);
    my @fUserAgent = sort(keys %userAgent);
    my @faFamily = sort(keys %aFamily);
    my @freferer = sort(keys %referer);
    my @frdomain = sort(keys %rdomain);
    my @fOS = sort(keys %OS);
    printFormatter(\%ip, \@fip, $logcount, "IPADDR");
    printFormatter(\%date, \@fdate, $logcount, "DATE");
    printFormatter(\%hour, \@fhour, $logcount, "HOUR");
    printFormatter(\%status, \@fstatus, $logcount, "STATUS");
    printFormatter(\%URL, \@fURL, $logcount, "URL");
    printFormatter(\%resource, \@fResource, $resCount, "RESOURCE");
    printFormatter(\%userAgent, \@fUserAgent, $logcount, "USER AGENT");
    printFormatter(\%aFamily, \@faFamily, $logcount, "BROWSER FAMILY");
    printFormatter(\%referer, \@freferer, $logcount, "REFERER");
    printFormatter(\%rdomain, \@frdomain, $logcount, "REFERER DOMAIN");
    printFormatter(\%OS, \@fOS, $logcount, "OPPERATING SYSTEM");
    print "\n\n$bs bytes have been served!\n";
```